# Is there a way to import a js file globally as soon as the html is loaded?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6

I have an `animation.js` file in my vue app and I want to import this file globally.

When I import the JavaScript file into `main.js`, I have the problem that the HTML is not fully loaded yet and therefore the classes I am looking for in the JavaScript file are not found.

If I simply include the JS file in index.html with the script tag, I have the problem that after building the classes are only found by the navbar and footer component, because these are used directly in `App.vue`. All other components of the website are in <routerview/> and are not found.

This is the `animation.js` file:

```
    const observerOpacity = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
        entries.forEach((entry) => {
            if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                entry.target.classList.add('animated-opacity');
            }
        });
    });

    const animatedOpacity = document.querySelectorAll('.animate-opacity');
    animatedOpacity.forEach((el) => observerOpacity.observe(el));
```

This is my main.js (with my failed import):

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import './resources/css/app.pcss'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from "./router/index.js"



createApp(App).use(router).mount('#app')

import './resources/js/animate.js'
```

I would like to find a way to import that `animate.js` globally and as soon as the dom is loaded complete.

Comment: You could use the mounted hook in your root Vue component (i.e. App.vue) to run your code after the component's DOM element has been mounted.

Comment: do you have a example

Comment: When i put it into App.vue, the js file applies only to the Footer and Navbar

Comment: You should make the Observer global to your app so that your components have a reference to it somehow. Then whenever you render new components that have html you want to observe, grab a reference to the observer and call [observe()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver/observe) on the elements that were just rendered.